# DJango how to manage redshift connection in a server

Tags: django, amazon-redshift

I am using redshift in my django application. I know we can use `psycopg2` for redshift, but i am planning to use the aws library `pip install redshift_connector`

Currently for every query in my view i run. So here I see its taking time to connect to redshift everytime and thats consuming time than then query time.

```
conn = redshift_connector.connect(
     host='host.docker.internal',
     database='dev',
     port=5439,
     user='user',
     password='kkshdjhjhsdj'
  )
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
data = cursor.fetchall()
```

I am not sure how django keeps connection live for database and effeciently handle.

If we have to use some thirdparty databases then how to handle connection. Can someone guide me what else needs to be taken care.